# Python eliminate a Large item with "del LargeItem" or "LargeItem= None" inside a function

Tags: python, performance, optimization, memory-management

I wish to delete a large item in Python ***inside a function***. Some forum suggest to use **del LargeObject** and other **LargeObject= None**. In term of performance (speed and reclaiming memory after deleting item) which is the best solution?

Comment: Be aware that neither will actually delete any object (on its own). Both simply remove a reference to that object!

Answer (score 2):

With regards to reclaiming the memory, there will be no difference; assuming the refcount of the object in both situations drops to 0, the memory will be reclaimed in exactly the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two statements is that `del` will remove `LargeObject` from the local namespace (resulting in a `NameError` if you try to use it).  The other will keep a `LargeObject` in the current namespace, but it's value will be `None` -- Most likely resulting in a `ValueError` or `TypeError` if you try to use it.  Otherwise, I don't really see much difference between the two approaches.  Either way, if you want to reclaim your memory, you need to make sure you don't have other references to `LargeObject` sitting around.

Answer (score 1):

I expect the `del LargeObject` call to be faster. It compiles to only one instruction:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def fdel(foo):
...     del foo
... 
>>> def freassign(foo):
...     foo = None
... 
>>> dis.dis(fdel)
  2           0 DELETE_FAST              0 (foo)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(freassign)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (foo)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

In both cases the ref count for your large object is lowered by 1, and if it reaches 0 it'll be removed from memory.

The speed difference is absolutely minimal though:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('f("")', 'from __main__ import fdel as f')
0.16321110725402832
>>> timeit.timeit('f("")', 'from __main__ import freassign as f')
0.1656031608581543
```

This is not something you need to worry about.

Comment: but if the large object is inside a function and I return a different object (derived from the large object), do i need del the Large Object?

Comment: @Gianni: Local variables in a function are cleaned up automatically when the function finishes, so the ref-count drops. If there are no other references to Large Object, it'll be cleaned up. Using `del` is thus not required.